# Is ExpressionEngine SE still alive?

Tags: discussion

I feel that ExpressionEngine SE is dying. Here's a screenshot of the homepage:

[image: This site is dead]

As you can see, almost everything is just bumped by community. Even the meta here is dead.

If fact, at this point of writing (2016 June), the highest amount of rep earned by a single user is 704.

Just to mention it, the chat is also dead:

[image: Dead Chat]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you are looking at is a side effect of the Community♦ user "bumping" old questions going into a lull over the weekend. The system is supposed to *bump* questions to the top of the 'activity' list that can use some more attention on occastion… but that process can become a bit overbearing under certain conditions. I have adjusted the site setting so the *bumping* will not fill more than 25% of the front page. We're discussing whether we should roll out this anomaly-handler network wide.

As a matter of fact, ExpressionEngine is still receives a healthy level of activity, averaging 4-5 questions per day, slowing down a bit in the summer months. That screen cap you posted is a distorted view of a site that didn't happen to get much use over a slow weekend, but hopefully we alleviated that effect.